# Rails Remote Debugging using RubyMine

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, debugging, remote-debugging, rubymine

I want to remotely debug my rails application, I am following the article [Remote Debugging](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/ruby/remote-debugging-with-product.html) by jetbrains. Following the instructions when I configure a remote interpreter using SSH Credentials I get the following error:

[image: Configuring Remote Interpreter]

I can confirm that the remote server is accessible and RubyMine is able to SSH it. It complains about the interpreter path but when I run `which ruby` on the server I get the same path `/usr/bin/ruby`

[image]

So the path is actually right. I am unable to figure out what is causing the problem for RubyMine, any help would be appreciated.

Remote Server Details:

- Fedora 13
- Ruby 1.8.6
- Rails 2.3.5

Comment: Could you please check how it goes with another Ruby version? 1.8.6 is no longer supported (https://www.jetbrains.com/help/ruby/supported-ruby-versions.html) In addition, please check how it goes in RubyMine 2020.1.

Comment: @Olivia Thank you for your response, the application is actually live on Ruby 1.8.6, can not change the ruby version for now.

Comment: Which RubyMine version are you using? Have you tried the latest one?

Comment: @Olivia I am using RubyMine 2019.3.3, it is a Feb 2020 release, so it is one of the latest versions.